# Using mod-rewrite to pass route to index.php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm kind of new to mod_rewrite so I need some help from you guys.

My folder structure is:

```
assets/fonts/       Contains all fonts
assets/images/      Contains all images
assets/scripts/     Contains all JavaScript files
assets/styles/      Contains all CSS files
pages/              Contains parts of the page as PHP file or directory containing PHP files
header.php          Header of site
footer.php          Footer of site
index.php           index of site, now always loads pages/home.php.
```

The pages directory contains all the body parts of the pages like home.php, about.php etc. It also contains directories like 'portfolio' which in turn contains more .php files.

This is how I'd like my urls to be re-written.

```
http://domain.com/about         => http://domain.com/index.php?route=about
http://domain.com/about/kittens => http://domain.com/index.php?route=about/kittens
```

This should however exclude requests directly to the `assests` or `pages` folder.
The reason why the pages folder should be excludes on direct requests like `http://domain.com/pages/about` is because some parts of the site are loaded with AJAX.
Preferable it would exclude any directory in the root.

Could you guys help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an approach along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|pages|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Save this as `.htaccess` in your root folder.

Comment: If you're running it on localhost remove the `/` from `/index.php` on the last line

Comment: That fixed it, but now my scripts and css are returning `index.php`

Comment: When you make a change like this, you may also need to update all your paths to `absolute` paths, for example `<link rel="stylehseet" href="/assets/styles/file.css" />` other wise they are relative and the browser will send a request to the wrong folder on the server. The trouble you will face with this is running the site as a virtual name sever locally.

Comment: If I enter the full path: `http://localhost/sitename/assets/styles/base.css`, I get a 404.

Comment: Is the .htaccess file in the sitename folder?

Comment: Yes, it's placed in the `sitename` folder.

Comment: The files do exist? This method works for me absolutely fine! Is mod_rewrite enabled on your local server? I can't think what else would cause this issue

Comment: The files exist and mod_rewrite is enabled. Strange.

Comment: Sorry Jon I wish I could help further

Comment: No problem, I'll ty on another web-server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31522/discussion-between-jon-koops-and-dale)