# How can I make profile pages accessible through "subdirectory"-like links?

Tags: php, html, subdirectory, user-profile

So I'm working on this website that will work like a social network in the sense that every user should have a profile page, accessible through a simple link that he/she can share with friends and stuff.

I perfectly understand how to do this by getting the data based on a name/id from a SQL database and properly displaying the select results. However I would only know how to do this by getting the id from `$_GET`, like this:

If the user opens `www.socialnetwork.com/profile.php?name=daniel`, I can look for `$_GET['name']` and take care of the rest.

But instead of doing it that way, I really wish the user page could be found through a link like this:
`www.socialnetwork.com/daniel` or at least `www.socialnetwork.com/profile/daniel`
So more like a fake sub-directory instead of an attribute.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which will give you something like `profile/daniel`, and then using a regular expression to parse the URL data.

Of course you'll also need to route those URLS to the PHP script through your web server conf.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MOD_REWRITE with .htaccess for that purpose.

This guide might help you: [Ultimate Guide to htaccess and mod_rewrite | Branded3](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/).

Check also this answer: [Using mod-rewrite to pass route to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021567/using-mod-rewrite-to-pass-route-to-index-php).

Particularly, this could help you (untested, please write some comments):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /profile/(.*) /profile.php?name=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Some more info on MOD_REWRITE: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)